# set value of class attribute of body element with ngClass

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to change class value if user signed in or not, I checked this in app.component.ts and login.component.ts here they are;

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  isAuthenticated:boolean;
  constructor(private auth:Auth){
      this.isAuthenticated=this.auth.authenticated();
  }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
 export class LoginComponent {
  isAuthenticated:boolean;   
  constructor(private auth:Auth){
    this.isAuthenticated=this.auth.authenticated();
  }
}
```

and index.html

```
<body [ngClass]="{
  'dashboard site-navbar-small' :isAuthenticated,
  'login-form login-form-second page-login-second' :!isAuthenticated
}">
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
```

but it doesnt work
here i how it looks in browser;
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me what it doesn't work?

Comment: I think its more clear with last edit, whats not work. I expect one class value set to attribute but you see its raw string of typescrpt code

Comment: how do you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

The root component of an angular app is inside the body tag : [Angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html) so we can not bind the body tag directly

And for now angular has give only Title service to get/set the title of the page

```
  export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  public constructor(private titleService:Title){
    this.titleService.setTitle('My ToDo');
  }
```

For body tag you can use setElementClass [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5ddzpOnIs4S5UWywVcnD?p=info) or you can use Jquery

```
setElementClass(document.body, "dashboard site-navbar-small", isAuthenticated)
setElementClass(document.body, "login-form login-form-second page-login-second", !isAuthenticated)
```

Comment: This makes sense but still cant solve, couldnt use this,renderer some how still on it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to move the logic from constructors just into simple functions? How is it supposed to work? Can you provide more informations about the logic in your code?

**`app.component.ts`**

```
export class AppComponent {
  isAuthenticated:boolean = false;

  private toggle(){
     this.isAuthenticated = !this.isAuthenticated;
  }
}
```

**`login.component.ts`**

```
 export class LoginComponent {
  isAuthenticated:boolean = false; 

   private toggle2(){
     this.isAuthenticated = !this.isAuthenticated;
  }
}
```

**`index.html`**

```
<body [ngClass]="{ 
  'dashboard site-navbar-small': isAuthenticated,
  'login-form login-form-second page-login-second': !isAuthenticated
}">
</body>
```

**Edit**

You are trying to bind a function to a boolean variable. Are you sure it has to look like this?
`this.isAuthenticated = this.auth.authenticated();`

Comment: it returns true or false ofc I am sure